Admob banner ad causing ANR (android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce)
i am getting a huge number of anr in my app on Google Play Console my threshold for anr is also crossed because of this admob banner ad. Stack trace are given below i think the problem in the webview there are three variants of the same anr showing google play console. i cannot reproduce it on my devices but the amount of affected users is huge. contacting  admob sdk team is also in vain they ask for sample project and in sample project its not reproducible. btw i am showing banner ad in overlay
1
#00  pc 0x000000000004def0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (syscall+32)
  #01  pc 0x000000000023247c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks+140)
  #02  pc 0x000000000056f0f4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI<false>::NewString+3940)
  #03  pc 0x0000000004e09958  /data/app/~~12CFHggruU0TDc6qnbVHvg==/com.google.android.webview-b_lImZKFG1Fqry3baMTuQg==/base.apk (BuildId: f8abf8bfd02bd0448e0af9433329cd13652d0d12)
  #04  pc 0x00000000025b05b4  /data/app/~~12CFHggruU0TDc6qnbVHvg==/com.google.android.webview-b_lImZKFG1Fqry3baMTuQg==/base.apk (BuildId: f8abf8bfd02bd0448e0af9433329cd13652d0d12)
  #05  pc 0x0000000004e3e3bc  /data/app/~~12CFHggruU0TDc6qnbVHvg==/com.google.android.webview-b_lImZKFG1Fqry3baMTuQg==/base.apk (BuildId: f8abf8bfd02bd0448e0af9433329cd13652d0d12)
  #06  pc 0x0000000004e3e468  /data/app/~~12CFHggruU0TDc6qnbVHvg==/com.google.android.webview-b_lImZKFG1Fqry3baMTuQg==/base.apk (BuildId: f8abf8bfd02bd0448e0af9433329cd13652d0d12)
  #07  pc 0x00000000032aab44  /data/app/~~12CFHggruU0TDc6qnbVHvg==/com.google.android.webview-b_lImZKFG1Fqry3baMTuQg==/base.apk (BuildId: f8abf8bfd02bd0448e0af9433329cd13652d0d12)
  #08  pc 0x00000000032aa958  /data/app/~~12CFHggruU0TDc6qnbVHvg==/com.google.android.webview-b_lImZKFG1Fqry3baMTuQg==/base.apk (BuildId: f8abf8bfd02bd0448e0af9433329cd13652d0d12)
  #09  pc 0x0000000002f2e4f4  /data/app/~~12CFHggruU0TDc6qnbVHvg==/com.google.android.webview-b_lImZKFG1Fqry3baMTuQg==/base.apk (BuildId: f8abf8bfd02bd0448e0af9433329cd13652d0d12)
  #10  pc 0x0000000002520530  /data/app/~~12CFHggruU0TDc6qnbVHvg==/com.google.android.webview-b_lImZKFG1Fqry3baMTuQg==/base.apk (BuildId: f8abf8bfd02bd0448e0af9433329cd13652d0d12)
  #11  pc 0x000000000251fe60  /data/app/~~12CFHggruU0TDc6qnbVHvg==/com.google.android.webview-b_lImZKFG1Fqry3baMTuQg==/base.apk (BuildId: f8abf8bfd02bd0448e0af9433329cd13652d0d12)
  #12  pc 0x0000000002520278  /data/app/~~12CFHggruU0TDc6qnbVHvg==/com.google.android.webview-b_lImZKFG1Fqry3baMTuQg==/base.apk (BuildId: f8abf8bfd02bd0448e0af9433329cd13652d0d12)
  #13  pc 0x00000000025123d0  /data/app/~~12CFHggruU0TDc6qnbVHvg==/com.google.android.webview-b_lImZKFG1Fqry3baMTuQg==/base.apk (BuildId: f8abf8bfd02bd0448e0af9433329cd13652d0d12)
  #14  pc 0x0000000002512000  /data/app/~~12CFHggruU0TDc6qnbVHvg==/com.google.android.webview-b_lImZKFG1Fqry3baMTuQg==/base.apk (BuildId: f8abf8bfd02bd0448e0af9433329cd13652d0d12)
  #15  pc 0x000000000251fde4  /data/app/~~12CFHggruU0TDc6qnbVHvg==/com.google.android.webview-b_lImZKFG1Fqry3baMTuQg==/base.apk (BuildId: f8abf8bfd02bd0448e0af9433329cd13652d0d12)
  #16  pc 0x000000000251f484  /data/app/~~12CFHggruU0TDc6qnbVHvg==/com.google.android.webview-b_lImZKFG1Fqry3baMTuQg==/base.apk (BuildId: f8abf8bfd02bd0448e0af9433329cd13652d0d12)
  #17  pc 0x000000000251e814  /data/app/~~12CFHggruU0TDc6qnbVHvg==/com.google.android.webview-b_lImZKFG1Fqry3baMTuQg==/base.apk (BuildId: f8abf8bfd02bd0448e0af9433329cd13652d0d12)
  #18  pc 0x000000000258a4dc  /data/app/~~12CFHggruU0TDc6qnbVHvg==/com.google.android.webview-b_lImZKFG1Fqry3baMTuQg==/base.apk (BuildId: f8abf8bfd02bd0448e0af9433329cd13652d0d12)
  #19  pc 0x0000000002586f20  /data/app/~~12CFHggruU0TDc6qnbVHvg==/com.google.android.webview-b_lImZKFG1Fqry3baMTuQg==/base.apk (BuildId: f8abf8bfd02bd0448e0af9433329cd13652d0d12)
  #20  pc 0x0000000004e06330  /data/app/~~12CFHggruU0TDc6qnbVHvg==/com.google.android.webview-b_lImZKFG1Fqry3baMTuQg==/base.apk (BuildId: f8abf8bfd02bd0448e0af9433329cd13652d0d12)
  #21  pc 0x0000000004e062e4  /data/app/~~12CFHggruU0TDc6qnbVHvg==/com.google.android.webview-b_lImZKFG1Fqry3baMTuQg==/base.apk (BuildId: f8abf8bfd02bd0448e0af9433329cd13652d0d12)
  #22  pc 0x000000000318d504  /data/app/~~12CFHggruU0TDc6qnbVHvg==/com.google.android.webview-b_lImZKFG1Fqry3baMTuQg==/base.apk (BuildId: f8abf8bfd02bd0448e0af9433329cd13652d0d12)
  #23  pc 0x0000000000018184  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner+916)
  #24  pc 0x0000000000017d84  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce+116)
  #25  pc 0x0000000000152f40  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce+48)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (Native method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next (MessageQueue.java:335)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:161)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:288)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7880)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:548)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1009)

other variant
  #00  pc 0x000000000004f55c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (syscall+28)
  #01  pc 0x000000000023247c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks+140)
  #02  pc 0x0000000000561124  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI<false>::CallVoidMethodV+988)
  #03  pc 0x0000000005f24fec  /data/app/~~CfDKHb-NgjyKq0UE4Y6zAg==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_636712333-K7MFldlCshIt9iuipME11g==/base.apk (BuildId: 930e6da4ab87612673f829f9908c9a2d3178e416)
  #04  pc 0x00000000072aa108  /data/app/~~CfDKHb-NgjyKq0UE4Y6zAg==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_636712333-K7MFldlCshIt9iuipME11g==/base.apk (BuildId: 930e6da4ab87612673f829f9908c9a2d3178e416)
  #05  pc 0x00000000072aa064  /data/app/~~CfDKHb-NgjyKq0UE4Y6zAg==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_636712333-K7MFldlCshIt9iuipME11g==/base.apk (BuildId: 930e6da4ab87612673f829f9908c9a2d3178e416)
  #06  pc 0x00000000049f28d4  /data/app/~~CfDKHb-NgjyKq0UE4Y6zAg==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_636712333-K7MFldlCshIt9iuipME11g==/base.apk (BuildId: 930e6da4ab87612673f829f9908c9a2d3178e416)
  #07  pc 0x0000000004a18e6c  /data/app/~~CfDKHb-NgjyKq0UE4Y6zAg==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_636712333-K7MFldlCshIt9iuipME11g==/base.apk (BuildId: 930e6da4ab87612673f829f9908c9a2d3178e416)
  #08  pc 0x0000000004a18e14  /data/app/~~CfDKHb-NgjyKq0UE4Y6zAg==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_636712333-K7MFldlCshIt9iuipME11g==/base.apk (BuildId: 930e6da4ab87612673f829f9908c9a2d3178e416)
  #09  pc 0x00000000071fd3f0  /data/app/~~CfDKHb-NgjyKq0UE4Y6zAg==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_636712333-K7MFldlCshIt9iuipME11g==/base.apk (BuildId: 930e6da4ab87612673f829f9908c9a2d3178e416)
  #10  pc 0x0000000000018224  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner+1060)
  #11  pc 0x0000000000017da0  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce+112)
  #12  pc 0x0000000000161d1c  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce+44)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (Native method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next (MessageQueue.java:335)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:161)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:288)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8061)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:703)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:923)

another variant
#00  pc 0x0000000000018cc4  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+28)
  #01  pc 0x00000000000b71cd  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks(art::Thread*)+80)
  #02  pc 0x00000000002ab23b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JNI::NewString(_JNIEnv*, unsigned short const*, int)+306)
  #03  pc 0x00000000011e6a6b  /data/app/com.android.chrome-NHrf__HP42m7eO5-f4AIIg==/base.apk
  #04  pc 0x000000000060c9a7  /data/app/com.android.chrome-NHrf__HP42m7eO5-f4AIIg==/base.apk
  #05  pc 0x00000000011f7e75  /data/app/com.android.chrome-NHrf__HP42m7eO5-f4AIIg==/base.apk
  #06  pc 0x00000000011f7ec1  /data/app/com.android.chrome-NHrf__HP42m7eO5-f4AIIg==/base.apk
  #07  pc 0x000000000026cebb  /data/app/com.android.chrome-NHrf__HP42m7eO5-f4AIIg==/base.apk
  #08  pc 0x000000000016c1c7  /data/app/com.android.chrome-NHrf__HP42m7eO5-f4AIIg==/base.apk
  #09  pc 0x0000000001121863  /data/app/com.android.chrome-NHrf__HP42m7eO5-f4AIIg==/base.apk
  #10  pc 0x0000000000ed9fe5  /data/app/com.android.chrome-NHrf__HP42m7eO5-f4AIIg==/base.apk
  #11  pc 0x0000000000ed8ee1  /data/app/com.android.chrome-NHrf__HP42m7eO5-f4AIIg==/base.apk
  #12  pc 0x0000000000d63f59  /data/app/com.android.chrome-NHrf__HP42m7eO5-f4AIIg==/base.apk
  #13  pc 0x0000000000ed81db  /data/app/com.android.chrome-NHrf__HP42m7eO5-f4AIIg==/base.apk
  #14  pc 0x0000000000ed8127  /data/app/com.android.chrome-NHrf__HP42m7eO5-f4AIIg==/base.apk
  #15  pc 0x0000000000ed7f53  /data/app/com.android.chrome-NHrf__HP42m7eO5-f4AIIg==/base.apk
  #16  pc 0x000000000111518b  /data/app/com.android.chrome-NHrf__HP42m7eO5-f4AIIg==/base.apk
  #17  pc 0x00000000010ec461  /data/app/com.android.chrome-NHrf__HP42m7eO5-f4AIIg==/base.apk
  #18  pc 0x0000000000a83825  /data/app/com.android.chrome-NHrf__HP42m7eO5-f4AIIg==/base.apk
  #19  pc 0x00000000010ebe2f  /data/app/com.android.chrome-NHrf__HP42m7eO5-f4AIIg==/base.apk
  #20  pc 0x00000000010ebcf3  /data/app/com.android.chrome-NHrf__HP42m7eO5-f4AIIg==/base.apk
  #21  pc 0x00000000000987b5  /data/app/com.android.chrome-NHrf__HP42m7eO5-f4AIIg==/base.apk
  #22  pc 0x00000000010ebc19  /data/app/com.android.chrome-NHrf__HP42m7eO5-f4AIIg==/base.apk
  #23  pc 0x00000000010ead03  /data/app/com.android.chrome-NHrf__HP42m7eO5-f4AIIg==/base.apk
  #24  pc 0x0000000000455795  /data/app/com.android.chrome-NHrf__HP42m7eO5-f4AIIg==/base.apk
  #25  pc 0x0000000000558cab  /data/app/com.android.chrome-NHrf__HP42m7eO5-f4AIIg==/base.apk
  #26  pc 0x0000000000595431  /data/app/com.android.chrome-NHrf__HP42m7eO5-f4AIIg==/base.apk
  #27  pc 0x0000000000594e59  /data/app/com.android.chrome-NHrf__HP42m7eO5-f4AIIg==/base.apk
  #28  pc 0x000000000059523d  /data/app/com.android.chrome-NHrf__HP42m7eO5-f4AIIg==/base.apk
  #29  pc 0x000000000058a4f1  /data/app/com.android.chrome-NHrf__HP42m7eO5-f4AIIg==/base.apk
  #30  pc 0x000000000058a229  /data/app/com.android.chrome-NHrf__HP42m7eO5-f4AIIg==/base.apk
  #31  pc 0x0000000000594e59  /data/app/com.android.chrome-NHrf__HP42m7eO5-f4AIIg==/base.apk
  #32  pc 0x000000000059482f  /data/app/com.android.chrome-NHrf__HP42m7eO5-f4AIIg==/base.apk
  #33  pc 0x0000000000593e59  /data/app/com.android.chrome-NHrf__HP42m7eO5-f4AIIg==/base.apk
  #34  pc 0x0000000000593dc5  /data/app/com.android.chrome-NHrf__HP42m7eO5-f4AIIg==/base.apk
  #35  pc 0x0000000000006a3f  /data/app/com.android.chrome-NHrf__HP42m7eO5-f4AIIg==/base.apk
  #36  pc 0x0000000000593cbd  /data/app/com.android.chrome-NHrf__HP42m7eO5-f4AIIg==/base.apk
  #37  pc 0x00000000005ee33b  /data/app/com.android.chrome-NHrf__HP42m7eO5-f4AIIg==/base.apk
  #38  pc 0x00000000005eba93  /data/app/com.android.chrome-NHrf__HP42m7eO5-f4AIIg==/base.apk
  #39  pc 0x00000000011d6d5d  /data/app/com.android.chrome-NHrf__HP42m7eO5-f4AIIg==/base.apk
  #40  pc 0x00000000011e359b  /data/app/com.android.chrome-NHrf__HP42m7eO5-f4AIIg==/base.apk
  #41  pc 0x00000000011e356f  /data/app/com.android.chrome-NHrf__HP42m7eO5-f4AIIg==/base.apk
  #42  pc 0x0000000000ff49fd  /data/app/com.android.chrome-NHrf__HP42m7eO5-f4AIIg==/base.apk
  #43  pc 0x00000000000101f1  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+572)
  #44  pc 0x000000000000ff1d  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+32)
  #45  pc 0x00000000000b3969  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NativeMessageQueue::pollOnce(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, int)+24)
  #46  pc 0x000000000019027d  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (Java_android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce__JI+92)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (Native method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next (MessageQueue.java:366)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:144)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6861)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:450)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:936)


Do you use an unity ads adapter? We are into the same investigation at the moment. And a retrospective check has shown a correlation with the time when unity ads mediation adapter was added

No i am using admob sdk in my android app
